r - Plot intersecting curves
I want to create a simple plot displaying two intersecting curves like the one below:

(with an arrow indicating the intersection point)
I have been able to draw the intersecting curves with the following code:
I0 <- log(1)
b <- .1
d <- .014

curve(exp(I0 - b * x), 0, 50, col = "blue", lwd = 2)
curve(exp(d * x) - 1, 0, 50, add = TRUE, col = "red", lwd = 2)

But what I got is not a pair of "symmetrical" curves:

Any hints? (For this example I did not try to plot the arrow).

curve(exp(I0 - b * x), 0, 30, col = "blue", lwd = 2); curve(exp(I0 - b * (30-x)), 0, 30, add = TRUE, col = "red", lwd = 2)?

and arrows(15, 0.5, y1 = 0.3, length = 0.1)

I feel sorry for d. Poor guy got left out.

And @Edward, let's "d" rest in peace. ;-)

How did you decide what d was in the first place?   How did you decide what the intersection point is or should be?    Your actual intent is unclear.

Hi, @Carl Witthoft! This pair of curves is a representation of the classical (and mostly theoretical) model of island biogeography (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Theory_of_Island_Biogeography). This plot is for illustrative purposes only.

BTW: I would like to have a text annotation at the end of the arrow (eg., "equilibrium number"), but could not find an explanation of something so basic. Could one of you wizards point some documentation for doing this (using R base graphics only)?

@maurobio   try  ?text

Hi, @Carl Witthoft! I tried: arrows(15, 0.4, y1 = 0.25, length = 0.1, lwd = 2);
text(15, 0.47, expression(hat(S))) and it worked fine! Thanks a lot!!

To find the point of intersection (your "d"), you can use uniroot.
f <- function(x) exp(I0 - b * x)
g <- function(x) exp(I0 - b * (30-x))
    
I0 <- log(1)
b <- 0.1

x <- uniroot(function(x) f(x) - g(x), interval=c(0,30))$root
y <- g(x)

curve(exp(I0 - b * x), 0, 30, col="blue", lwd=2)
curve(exp(I0 - b * (30-x)), 0, 30, col="red", lwd=2, add=TRUE)

y.axs <- par("usr")[3:4]
y0 <- y + diff(y.axs) / 10

arrows(x0=x, y0=y0, x1=x, y1=y, length = 0.15)
text(x=x, y=y0, expression(hat(S)), pos=3)



Hi, @Edward! Great! I didn't know the uniroot() function. Thanks!
